# XCode 13.1 Failed to generate coverage for target 'xx.app' at paths

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

Failed to generate coverage for target 'xx.app' at paths (
"/Users/bupozhuang/DeriveData/xxDemo-aacxrfgumjzqjncgymjnenzofsub/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xx.app/xx"
): Malformed coverage data

I would be very grateful if anyone could help